# How to get all Ids from array embedded within array using Lodash?

Tags: lodash, sub-array, subdocument

I have this 'Products' array (contain 'Product' sub documents, each with its own unique Id):

```
Products: [ 
            { listPrice: '1.90', Product: {id: 'xxx1'} },
            { listPrice: '3.90', Product: {id: 'xxx2'} },
            { listPrice: '5.90', Product: {id: 'xxx3'} }
          ]
```

I want to get this result below using Lodash:

```
filterIds = ['xxx1', 'xxx2', 'xxx3'];
```

In my code, this is what I wrote:

```
filterIds = _.map(this.Products.Product, 'id');
```

But it just returns [ ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using vanilla JS's [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) method like so:

```js
const arr = [{listPrice:'1.90',Product:{id:'xxx1'}},{listPrice:'3.90',Product:{id:'xxx2'}},{listPrice:'5.90',Product:{id:'xxx3'}}],

filtered = arr.map(obj => obj.Product.id);
console.log(filtered);
```

If you must use lodash:

```js
const arr = [{listPrice:'1.90',Product:{id:'xxx1'}},{listPrice:'3.90',Product:{id:'xxx2'}},{listPrice:'5.90',Product:{id:'xxx3'}}],

res = _.map(arr, obj => obj.Product.id);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Lodash

```
    const _ = require('lodash');
    const Products= [
        { listPrice: '1.90', Product: {id: 'xxx1'} },
        { listPrice: '3.90', Product: {id: 'xxx2'} },
        { listPrice: '5.90', Product: {id: 'xxx3'} }
    ]
    console.log(_.map(_.map(Products, 'Product'), 'id'));
    //[ 'xxx1', 'xxx2', 'xxx3' ]
```